# Common way to namespace AngularJS modules?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, namespaces

I'm new to AngularJS and am brainstorming ways to namespace modules in my application.

One constraint is that I need to be able to embed my Angular app inside a placeholder div inside a third-party web site (which could possibly also use Angular), without using an iframe. So, I can't simply create my modules without a namespace, like `angular.module('users')`, as this could conflict with any 'users' module already defined in the third-party app.

I've arrived at the following organization:

```
angular.module('mycompany.productname', [
    'ngRoute',
    'mycompany.productname.forms',
    'mycompany.productname.users',
    'mycompany.productname.services'
]);

angular.module('mycompany.productname.forms').controller('formEditController', ['$scope', function($scope) { ...

angular.module('mycompany.productname.users').controller('userAccountController', ['$scope', function($scope) { ...

angular.module('mycompany.productname.users').controller('userLoginController', ['$scope', function($scope) { ...

angular.module('mycompany.productname.services').service('forms', ['$scope', function($scope) { ...
```

Is there a more common solution, given my constraints above?

Comment: Looks pretty good. I like to name things very similarly :)

Comment: Why are we voting to close this question? Is it not objective enough for you people or something? Watch this question receive 1,000 views within the next 4 months.

Answer (score 0):

I have been tinkering lately with a concept by @jdp https://github.com/jdpedrie/angular-package-loader which keeps things tidy.